# jquery validation - optional field

Tags: jquery

In a registration form middleName field is optional. When the users enters his/her middleName, then it should validate that field.

I have used the following code to achieve the above scenario, but it is not working.

```
$("#middleName").rules("add", {checkName: true, required: false, messages: {checkName: "Please enter a valid middle name"} });

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkName",
        function(value, element) {
            var regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s|\,|\.|\-|\']+$/);
            return regExp.test(value);
        },
        "Please enter a valid name."
);
```

Can anyone suggest me to achieve the above scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your custom methods you need to add the optional clause, like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkName", function(value, element) {
  var regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s|\,|\.|\-|\']+$/);
  return this.optional(element) || regExp.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid name.");
```

You can see examples like this in the validation library's [additional methods file](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js) as a reference, basically this just adds a sanity/"am I even required?" check to the result.

Comment: Nick, the character class has redundant (probably useless/unintended) pipes and unnecessary escaping backslashes in it.  Please correct this character class so that copy-pasta developers aren't using this suboptimal pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

You can use this in two ways. When you want it as optional field then say "checkName: optional".

```
$("#middleName").rules("add", {checkName: 'opt', messages: {checkName: "Please enter a valid middle name"} });
```

When you want it as required field then say `checkName: 'true'`

```
$("#middleName").rules("add", {checkName: true, messages: {checkName: "Please enter a valid middle name"} });
```

and your rules would be

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkName", function(value, element, param) {
  var regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s|\,|\.|\-|\']+$/);
  if(param == 'opt'){
      return this.optional(element) || regExp.test(value);
  }else{
      return regExp.test(value);
  }
}, "Please enter a valid name.");
```

best of luck

Comment: The character class has redundant (probably useless/unintended) pipes and unnecessary escaping backslashes in it.  Please correct this character class so that copy-pasta developers aren't using this suboptimal pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
jQuery("#middlename").bind("KeyUp").function(validateMiddleName());
```

and then

```
function validateMiddleName()
{
    if (jQuery("#middlename"))
    {
        //Do the validation
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure that the syntax is 100%, but you get the idea.